# Why is my dog so plump? Does he need to go on a diet?

Tags: nintendogs-and-cats

I walk my dog twice a day and only feed him when he is hungry. I try not to give him too many treats, but when I was trying to train him to play dead, he ate quite a few before I figured out how to use them.

Now he is plump and I don't want him to be that way - I would prefer to get him back to his ideal physique that he had before.

What do I need to do? I tried long walks and more exercise but it doesn't seem to help - do I just have to keep working at it? Or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you noticed your dog is plump and want him to slim down, you simply need to walk him and feed him Diet Food.

Diet Dog Food can be bought from BARC for $5 after being unlocked with 850 Owner Points or by playing 6 days.

Comment: Ah, so he does need to go on a diet....

Answer (score 1):

Just keep that up, also feed him diet food, but *don't* feed him diet food once he is the weight/size you want him to be. It will make him under fed. Also feed him water. Diet food can be bought at barc once you have 850 owner points or have been playing for 6 days. Never feed your dog wet food, or formula. It is very fattening. Only use it when your dog is too skinny or underfed.

Answer (score 0):

If your dog is plump, feed it diet food. This can be bought at the store after you have unlocked 850 trainer points. When your dog is ideal or skinny, stop feeding it diet food! I already made that mistake.

If you don't know what drink to buy, buy milk, water, and if your dog is still a pup, formula.